# Download PDFs iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, nsurlconnection, nsdata, download

I am having trouble downloading multiple PDF files from a weblink. The code I have can find the files on the web server but it only downloads about 360 bytes. Each file is about 2-3 MB, which when read produces %PDF, which to my understanding is the beginning bytes of a PDF.

What happens with this code is it is passed a string that then accesses a dictionary from a plist file that was just downloaded from the same web server that contains the PDF files. The string then gets the actual name of the PDF that is on the web server and gets downloaded to an NSData object via NSURLConnection. Finally it is written to the Apps Documents directory.

Any help would be amazing!

-(void)fileToDownload:(NSString *)stringToPDFName
{

```
NSString *downloadfile = [[masterDictionary objectForKey:@"PDF Dictionary"] objectForKey:stringToPDFName];
NSLog(@"downloadFile: %@",downloadfile);

NSString *pathToFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.pdf",staticURLToPDF,downloadfile];
NSLog(@"pathToFile: %@",pathToFile);
NSError *error;

if ([listOfPDFsAlreadyDownloaded containsObject:pathToFile]) {
    NSLog(@"File Already Downloaded From New List: %@", [pathToFile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:staticURLToPDF withString:@""]);
} else {
    //download new file
    NSString *urlString = [[staticURLToPDF stringByAppendingPathComponent:downloadfile] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@".pdf"];

    NSData *pdfDownloading = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] returningResponse:NULL error:&error];


    NSLog(@"pdfDownloading Data: %@, Error: %@", pdfDownloading,error);

    BOOL written = [pdfDownloading writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/POGs/%@.pdf",documentsDirectory,downloadfile] atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"FileDownloading %@/POGs/%@.pdf",documentsDirectory,downloadfile);

    if (written) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
        downloadedDocuments++;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File Didn't Save");
    }
    [listOfPDFsAlreadyDownloaded addObject:pathToFile];
    NSLog(@"File to Download: %@",[pathToFile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:staticURLToPDF withString:@""]);
    NSLog(@"%i documentsDownloaded",downloadedDocuments);
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look into NSURLConnection - using this you issue should be solved

Comment: Look at http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/

Comment: You don't seem I have any asynchrony here; I think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `NSURLSession`, especially `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` to download files.

I recommend starting with Apple's official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html

And please don't do synchronous requests. Networks are inherently slow, so tasks should always happen asynchronously.